# How to add a shortcut for changing keyboard language ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

I'm new to Ubuntu
I want to now how I can add a shortcut like alt+shift in windows to change the keyboard language 
thank you